# working out a particular pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Hi javascript coders!,

I have some code that I have been trying to figure out. It is basically an application in d3 that colours the map of a country based on data and according to some chosen threshold. A program is said to be written in particular pattern which is said to be:

```
 //program pattern
const compose = (...fns) => (arg) => 
 fns.reduce((composed, f) => f(composed), arg)
```

Also this compose function is used in the main function of a file

```
var drawMap = (categoryName, subCategory, subSubCategory, colorFunction=defaultColorFunction) => {

    var getArrayOfCategory = getArrayOfCategoryByName(categoryName),
        colorArrayBuilder = createColorArrayBuilder(colorFunction),
        d3SvgMap = d3.select("svg#svg2"),
        colorMap =  createColorMap(d3SvgMap),
        hoverTipString = subSubCategory + " " + subCategory.toLowerCase(),
        hoverEffects = addHoverEffects(d3SvgMap)(hoverTipString),
        currentRenderArray = getCurrentRenderArray(C.defaultMainCategory, subCategory, subSubCategory),
        d3SvgPyramid = d3.select("svg#"+C.pyramidSvgId),
        pyramidChart = drawPyramidChart(d3SvgPyramid),
        handler =   compose(
                        currentRenderArray,
                        hoverEffects,
                        colorArrayBuilder,
                        pyramidChart,
                        colorMap
                    )

        getArrayOfCategory(handler)
}
```

Can anybody explain this pattern to me like in simple words and tell me what the purpose of the handler function is in drawMap.

Im really stuck to understand this so any help would be apreciated.

Thank in advance

Comment: Compose function is just function that get [fn1, fn2, fn3] and return new function `function(...args) { return fn1(fn2(fn3(...args))); }` (or in oposite direction, I'm never sure and always need to check) and this is what your handler function is, it calling all those function and pass the return value of one function to next function.

Comment: This is not really a design pattern at all, it's just [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

Comment: this handler also appears here, how could it be explained here?                    var getArrayOfCategoryByName = categoryName => handler => {
 var localStorageCategory = localStorage[categoryName],
  parsed,
  result;
 if (localStorageCategory) {
  parsed = JSON.parse(localStorageCategory)
  result = handler(parsed)
 } else {
  d3.text('data/'+categoryName+'.csv').then(response => {
   parsed = d3.csvParseRows(response)
   result = handler(parsed)
   localStorage[categoryName] = JSON.stringify(parsed)
  })
 }

 return result
}